# OOP: Any idiom for easy interface extraction and less verbose auto-forwarding?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, lisp, composition

---

**EDIT**

*Even though I use a pseudo-Java syntax below for illustration, this question is NOT limited to any 1 programming language. Please feel free to post an idiom or language-provided mechanism from your favorite programming language.*

---

When attempting to reuse an existing class, `Old`, via composition instead of inheritance, it is very tedious to first manually create a new interface out of the existing class, and then write forwarding functions in `New`. The exercise becomes especially wasteful if `Old` has tons of public methods in it and whereas you need to override only a handful of them.

Ignoring IDE's like Eclipse that though can help with this process but still cannot reduce the resulting verbosity of code that one has to read and maintain, it would greatly help to have a couple language mechanisms to...

1. automatically extract the public methods of `Old`, say, via an `interfaceOf` operator; and
2. by default forward all automatically generated interface methods of `Old` , say, via a `forwardsTo` operator, to a composed instance of `Old`, with you only providing definitions for the handful of methods you wish to override in `New`.

An example:

```
// A hypothetical, Java-like language
class Old { 
    public void a() { }
    public void b() { }
    public void c() { }

    private void d() { }
    protected void e() { }
    // ...
}

class New implements interfaceOf Old {
    public New() {
        // This would auto-forward all Old methods to _composed
        // except the ones overridden in New.

        Old forwardsTo _composed;
    }

    // The only method of Old that is being overridden in New.
    public void b() {
        _composed.b();
    }

    private Old _composed;
}
```

My question is:

1. Is this possible at the **code level** (say, via some **reusable** design pattern, or idiom), so that the result is minimal verbosity in `New` and classes like `New`?
2. Are there any other languages where such mechanisms are provided?

**EDIT**

Now, I don't know these languages in detail but I'm hoping that 'Lispy' languages like Scheme, Lisp, Clojure won't disappoint here... for Lisp after all is a *'programmable programming language'* (according to Paul Graham and perhaps others).

**EDIT 2**

I may not be the author of `Old` or may not want to change its source code, effectively wanting to use it as a blackbox.

Comment: 'Lisp' in general is not a class based object-oriented language, but a family of programming language, mostly combining imperative, procedural and functional styles. Some Lisps, like Common Lisp have object-oriented functionality, but if you have a real question about that, then you should ask a specific question. As it is currently, there are huge differences in OO which would make an answer not very useful and it would not solve an problem you have with Java.

Comment: If something can be done in Java, then great, but I'm not looking for specifically a Java solution - Common Lisp should be just fine. I remember Paul Graham's ACL book mentioning that ACL supports programming paradigms like OOP, AOP, etc right "out of the box", requiring no language extension at the compiler level. What I don't know is if the above use-case is supported by Common Lisp (or, any other similar Lisp's) or other languages. Hence, the question.

Comment: which real problem do you try to solve? It does not help you to know about Common Lisp. OOP in Common Lisp works differently from Java. Hint: use Smalltalk.

Comment: Let the OP be the judge of what helps him or not, please. This an **OOP** question that could have (and I don't know that for sure, and which is why I posted this question in the first place!) a solution via an idiom, a design pattern, via meta-programming, in multiple programming languages and not just Java. Again, this is not a programming question for any specific programming language. I welcome PHP and GoLang solutions posted so far, and am looking for more such ideas... unless you close-voters know better than me what I wanted to ask and why.

Comment: The quote "Lisp is a programmable programming language" is from John Foderaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in languages that allow you to specify a  catch-all magic method (eg. `__call()` in php). You could catch any function call here that you have not specifically overriden, check if it exists in class `Old` and if it does, just forward the call.

Something like this:

```
public function __call($name, $args)
{
  if (method_exists($old, $name))
  {
    call_user_func([$obj, $name], $args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Go has such a mechanism, a struct can embed methods from another struct.

Take a look [here](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/inheritance-and-subclassing-in-go-or.html). This could be what you are asking as second question.

Answer (score 1):

#### First, to answer the design question in the context of "OOP" (class-oriented) languages:

If you really need to replace `Old` with its complete interface `IOld` everywhere you use it, just to make `New`, which implements `IOld`, behave like you want, then you actually should use inheritance.

If you only need a small part of `IOld` for `New`, then you should only put that part into the interface `ICommon` and let both `Old` and `New` implement it.  In this case, you would only replace `Old` by `ICommon` where both `Old` and `New` make sense.

#### Second, what can Common Lisp do for you in such a case?

Common Lisp is very different from Java and other class-oriented languages.

Just a few pointers:  In Common Lisp, objects are primarily used to structure and categorize data, not code.  You won't find "one class per file", "one file per class", or "package names completely correspond to directory structure" here.  Methods do not "belong" to classes but to *generic functions* whose sole responsibility it is to dispatch according to the classes of their arguments (which has the nice side effect of enabling a seamless multiple dispatch).  There is multiple inheritance.  There are no interfaces as such.  There is a much stronger tendency to use packages for modularity instead of just organizing classes.  Which symbols are exported ("public" in Java parlance) is defined per package, not per class (which would not make sense with the above obviously).

I think that your problem would either completely disappear in a Common Lisp environment because your code is not forced into a class structure, or be quite naturally solved or expressed in terms of multiple dispatch and/or (maybe multiple) inheritance.

One would need at least a complete example and large parts of the surrounding system to even attempt a translation into Common Lisp idioms.  You just write code so differently that it would not make any sense to try a one-to-one translation of a few forms.

Comment: Now re: your 'First' section 2nd para, I think you've changed the original problem I posed. Namely: I have only `Old`  with me; I want to reuse it via composition instead of inheritance; I don't want to tediously - and verbosely - create various `IOld`'s by hand or even with an IDE like Eclipse; I may not be the author of `Old` or may not want to touch `Old`'s code for other reasons, so I'd like to treat `Old` as a blackbox; finally, I want the whole of `IOld` to be available so that I can override arbitrary subsets of it, and autoforward the rest to the composed instance of `Old`.

Comment: If you cannot modify `Old`, then you can't make it `implement` `IOld` (or `extend` `AbstractOld`) either, can you?  It seems that you need the _facade_, and that means either typing a lot or using Reflection, which has its own perils.